# robotframework: InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters: '\xe5'

Tags: utf-8, robotframework, urlencode

my http url params contains Chinese Word 内科 as below:

> [https://testsite.com/api/register?cid=2&deptid=493c3102-1e48-436c-9f6a-d7720335fab1&deptName=内科&](https://testsite.com/api/register?cid=2&deptid=493c3102-1e48-436c-9f6a-d7720335fab1&deptName=%E5%86%85%E7%A7%91&)

default encoding is UTF-8. 内科 is encoded as \xe5\x86\x85\xe7\xa7\x91

when request the url, RF HttpLibrary.HTTP.Post report error:
FAIL : InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters... (found at least '\xe5')

how to solve this coding issue? thanks in advance!

tried urlencode again,but now work

Comment: httplib.py:   self._validate_path(url),  _contains_disallowed_url_pchar_re = re.compile('[\x00-\x20\x7f-\xff]'), here reported the error.

Comment: I have found the workaround: urlencode first, use the encoded url in RF.